# How to handle authorization for an index route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to hide posts from specific users. Only The Creator of the post can edit or view the posts.

Everything works fine for my show view.

My PostController:

```
public function show($id)
{
    //auth()->loginUsingId(3);

    // Find Blog post by id
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    if(Gate::denies('show-post', $post)) {
      abort(403, 'Access denied');
    };

    return view('posts.show')->withPost($post);
}
```

However I have no Idea how to do same thing for my index view. I can't pass a paramter to index(***$id***).

Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization

Comment: Thank you panagiotis, this was the example I was working with. Again, everything works fine with my show method. But I have no Idea how to implement it with my index method

Comment: @SteveBrown : the index method should return all the posts created by the user ?

Comment: @Moppo: Yes, the index method should return only the posts created by the user and hide posts from other users

Comment: @SteveBrown post your relation between user & post to help you take user's posts

Answer (score 2):

If the index view should return only the posts created by the user, you should to something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    //get the auth user id
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    //get only the posts where the user is the owner
    $posts = Post::where('owner', $user_id)->get();      

    return view('posts.index')->withPost($posts);
}
```

you don't need to use the `Gate` facade here, as you're sure you're getting only the posts the current authenticated user can access

Comment: hmmmm This throws me an error -> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'owner' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `owner` = 7)

Comment: @SteveBrown : the column name is only an example, you should replace it with the name of the column of the  post owner in your database, if you have one. If you don't have a column for the owner you should create one and populate it when creating the post. Or you should use the actual relation you have between post and users to get only the post created by the user

Comment: Woohooooo, Thanks!

Comment: @SteveBrown : if the solutions is good enough, please consider accepting / upvoting